# vb.net untyped arguments

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have an argument of any type? Here's what i mean:

```
some_function(argument)
    if (argument type is string)
        do something with a string
    else if (argument type is datarow)
        do something with a data row
    ...
```

I've found something about generics, but i'm not sure if it's what i want.

Comment: Then please describe what you want, so people can give you a decent solution that actually fits the real problem at hand.

Comment: I think i've described it pretty clearly. I need a method to accept an untyped argument and find its type dynamically. What's not clear about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can totally do it like this:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal arg As Object)
    If TypeOf arg Is TypeX Then
        DoSomethingX(DirectCast(arg, TypeX)
    ElseIf TypeOf arg Is TypeY Then
        DoSomethingY(DirectCast(arg, TypeY))
    End If
End Sub
```

**But**: at least first *ask yourself* if you're trying to do what should really be done with inheritance and polymorphism.

That's a big word for basically this:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseType
    Public MustOverride Sub DoSomething()
End Class

Public Class TypeX
    Inherits BaseType

    Public Overrides Sub DoSomething()
        ' Whatever TypeX does. '
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TypeY
    Inherits BaseType

    Public Overrides Sub DoSomething()
        ' Whatever TypeY does. '
    End Sub
End Class
```

It looks like a lot of typing, but then down the road any time you have an object of type `BaseType`, instead of a bunch of `If`/`ElseIf` checks, you just do:

```
arg.DoSomething()
```

Might not be the solution in your case. Just wanted to point out that this exists, and *might* be a better solution to your problem (hard to say without details).

Comment: Inheritance would be nice, sure, but this is not the case in which i can do that. Thanks for the example!

Comment: Better to use overloading, rather than `TypeOf Is` ? As in my answer :)

Comment: @MarkJ: That does not work if the parameter is typed as `Object` in code.

Answer (score 0):

one way is that you can use base type. Set the argument as Object.

```
some_function(argument as Object)
if (argument type is string)
    do something with a string
else if (argument type is datarow)
    do something with a data row
```

Comment: I guess it's a good idea, since i'll only pass in object descendant types. All i need now is a way to check the type and cast the object, but that's something google should help me with so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973896.aspx). Create methods that have the same name but different argument lists. Visual Basic .NET figures out which method to call during compile based on the parameter types that you pass.

```
  Sub some_function(ByVal argument As String)

  End Sub
  Sub some_function(ByVal argument As DataRow)

  End Sub
```